# Busqueda de resultados PARECIDOS O SIMILARES en Laravel5.5 o MYSQL

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Buenas a todos.. Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Laravel 5.5 y tengo una duda con una consulta a mi base de datos...
tengo una tabla llamada **CUTTER (el nombre no interesa mucho)** que asigna un codigo dependiendo la similitud del apellido de una persona, los datos de mi tabla estan almacenados de esta manera:
[image: muestra de mi base de datos]

**cod_cutter** es el codigo que se debe asignar dependiendo el apellido, y **nom_cutter** es el parecido que debe tener el apellido...
Ahora lo que estoy intentando hacer es: que si un apellido **ejemplo: Montemayor**, busque en la base de datos y le asigne el codigo por defecto **en este caso: 777** (segun la base de datos).
He intentado usar la consulta **LIKE** pero como el apellido ingresado es completo **(Montemayor)** y en la base de datos tengo solo un indicador similar **(Montem)**, me sale **0 resultados**. Y yo necesito que el codigo se asigne automaticamente dependiendo la similitud mas cercana del apellido ingresado por el usuario.
Alguna solución para que funcione en **LARAVEL5.5** o simplente en **MYSQL**?? Se agradece mucho sus respuestas...

Answer (score -1):

Prueba

```
Select * from CUTTER where nom_cutter like 'mont%'
```

Obtendrás todos los nombres que comiencen por 'mont'. Si haces:

```
Select *from CUTTER where nom_cutter like '%nt%'
```

Obtendrás todos los nombres que contienen nt, sin importar su posición.

Espero haberte ayudado.
saludos